# Why is the state of a variable not updating correctly in the parent class

Tags: reactjs, react-state-management, react-state

```
...
super(props)
this.state = {
  cartAddedCount: 0,
  itemNum: null,
  itemAdded: []
}
...
cartAdd(e) {
  let allItem = this.state.itemNum
  let itemN = e.target.name !== null ? e.target.name.toString().split('_')[1] : null
  let newItems = allItem !== null ? allItem + "," + itemN : itemN
  this.setState((prevState) => {
    return {
      cartAddedCount: prevState.cartAddedCount + 1,
      itemNum: newItems
    }
  })
  console.log(this.state.itemNum)
}

generateProductList(pd) { //pd is an an array of objects
  var prodList = []
  var prodDLen = 5
  for (var t = 0; t < prodDLen; t++) {
    prodList.push(
      <button name={"item_" + pd.productData[t].id} onClick={(e) => this.cartAdd(e)}>Buy Now</button>
    )
  }
  return prodList
}
...
<SCart count={this.state.cartAddedCount} iNum={this.state.itemNum} openM={this.manageCartModal} />
```

Why is it in when I click "Buy Now" the first time, in my parent class state, cartAddedCount is 0 and itemNum is null, second time I click, cartAddedCount is 1 and itemNum is 1

However SCart gets the `count` of 1 the first click and 2 the second click and so forth.

How do I resolve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

This is where the problem is

```
this.setState((prevState) => {
    return {
      cartAddedCount: prevState.cartAddedCount + 1,
      itemNum: newItems
    }
  })
  console.log(this.state.itemNum)
```

react `setState` method is not synchronous. to see what was set to state right after `setState` call use the call back function like below

```
this.setState((prevState) => {
    return {
      cartAddedCount: prevState.cartAddedCount + 1,
      itemNum: newItems
    }
  }, () => console.log(this.state.itemNum))
```

Comment: Ahhhhh so it does update correctly but only notice it after the fact.

Comment: That actually didn't work for me. Once I clicked another button in the same Component and opened a popup and tried to display the variable in the popup it was `null`.

Comment: I don't undeerstand